# Concurrency context switching of 2+ youtube videos on a dual core machine

Tags: concurrency, context-switch

From what I know, concurrency involves context switching if the number of software threads exceeds the number of physical cores. So, for example, if there's 4 software threads running on 1 physical core, then each software thread would take turns running, and no more than 1 software thread can be making progress simultaneously/in parallel.

I'm trying to apply this idea to youtube videos on my macbook pro. I have 2 cores, and I started 4 youtube videos (which I assume is basically 4 software threads) within a second of each other and played each to the 1 minute mark. Since I have 2 cores, I was under the impression that a maximum of 2 youtube videos can be making progress simultaneously. My eyes and ears perceived that all 4 videos were making progress in parallel and it didn't sound or look like any video was being paused, but I assumed this was because the context switching is occurring at a frequency that is not detectable by my senses.

So I then I set a timer to see how long it takes the 4 videos to get to the 1 minute mark when I start all 4 at approximately the same time (within 1 second of each other.) The 4 videos took approximately 1minute TOTAL to get to the 1 minute mark. I'm confused why it doesn't take at least 2 minutes when I only have 2 cores, so a maximum of 2 videos can be making progress simultaneously (and this is the best case scenario assuming my computer wasn't doing anything else but playing the youtube videos).

It appears that I'm misunderstanding something about concurrency/context switching because I don't see how it all 4 videos can get to the 1 minute mark in a minute. Could someone explain?

Comment: You can't measure this using video playback. Video playback involves delays for frame timing where other processes (videos) can play just fine. Measure it with tasks that don't involve timing, for instance, video encoding.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Could you explain in more detail what "delays for frame timing" mean in the context of concurrency? I don't understand.

Comment: It means if you're playing video with 60 frames/sec, once you paint one frame on screen, you have to wait to paint the next frame so the time difference between the two is 1/60 secs.

Comment: @Burak Serdar Ohh I get it. So you were saying that between the frames, the other videos may be playing. If the frame rate was instead equal to the frequency of my processor, would that mean the 4 videos would take at least 2 minutes?

Comment: This statement is not correct "...the frame rate was instead equal to the frequency of my processor...". This is not only related to the processor speed.  The point is you cannot measure context switching overhead with a program that relies on timing. Video playback relies on timing, and so are i/o-heavy tasks.